# Where is my mistake in this problem (finding indefinite integral using trig identities)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I am learning calculus.  Currently I am studying integration using trigonometric identities.

I encountered this problem and gave it a try.  My answer was incorrect.  I then sought the correct answer, and I see now why it is correct and why the method used to solve it was better than mine.  Here is my issue: I can not for the life of me find where my error was.  **Why is this answer wrong?**  I numbered the steps and explained my thinking.  Here is the problem:

> $$\int \tan^5(x)\cdot \sec^4(x) \,dx$$

I began by looking over my list of trig identities and derivatives, and I found these two which appeared helpful.  My thinking was that I could get the derivative of $\tan(x)$ and then use the identity to express everything that remains in terms of secants to use u-substitution.

> $\sec^2(x)-1=\tan^2(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\sec(x)=\tan(x)\cdot sec(x)$

First I got $\tan x \cdot \sec x$ by itself:

1. $$\int \left[\tan^5(x)\cdot \sec^4(x) \right] \,dx = \int \left[\tan^4(x)\cdot \sec^3(x)\cdot \tan(x)\cdot \sec(x) \right] dx$$

Then I broke the remaining tangent terms into $\tan^2x$ terms:

2. $$= \int \left[\tan^2(x)\cdot \tan^2(x) \cdot \sec^3(x)\cdot \tan(x)\cdot \sec(x) \right] \,dx$$

Then I replaced each $\tan^2x$ term by its equivalent term in secants:

3. $$=\int \left[ \left(\sec^2(x)-1 \right)\cdot \left(\sec^2(x)-1 \right)\cdot \sec^3(x)\cdot \tan(x)\cdot \sec(x) \right] \,dx$$

Then I distributed all my secant terms:

4. $$=\int \left[(\sec^4(x)-2 \sec^2(x)+1)(\sec^3(x))\cdot \tan(x)\cdot \sec(x) \right] \,dx$$
5. $$=\int \left[ \left(\sec^7(x)-2 \sec^5(x)+ \sec^3(x) \right)\cdot \tan(x)\cdot \sec(x) \right] dx$$

Then I applied this substitution:

6. $u=\sec(x)$, and then $\,du=\tan(x)\sec(x) dx$

Applying the substitution:

7. $$=\int \left(u^7-2u^5+u^3 \right) \,du$$

Integrating:

8. $$=\frac{u^8}{8}-\frac{2u^6}{6}+\frac{u^4}{4}+C$$

And then substituting back in:

9. $$=\frac{1}{8} \sec^8(x)-\frac{1}{3} \sec^6(x)+\frac{1}{4} \sec^4(x)+C$$

**Of course, this answer is wrong.**  I would love to know where I went wrong!

EDIT: I forgot to say, please forgive errors in the mathjax -- I'm a rank beginner!

Comment: Why do you say that your answer is wrong?

Comment: Only thing I see that is wrong is that you flipped a sign at the last step.

Comment: @AdamRubinson the very first step (without numbering) and the step 6 are enough.

Comment: @user317176 Thanks - I fixed the sign.  That was a typing error only.  Thanks!

Comment: Your answer looks right to me. It would look different had you used a $u=\tan x$ substitution but your answer looks correct for a $u=\sec x$ substitution.

Comment: I recommend graphing your answer and the answer you are expecting, to see if they are really different.

Comment: I double-checked and found nothing wrong with your answer.

Comment: With trigonometric integrals it occurs often that the result looks different from the "official" one, but the trick is that they only differ in an additive constant.

Comment: @nuggethead your result is correct. Difference between the yours and the other is just a constant. If I am not mistaken, it is 1/24.

Comment: **Moral.** Determining whether two functions differ by a constant is *hard*, in a sense that can be made precise.

Comment: Even though your answer isn't wrong, unfortunately in my experience there's a decent chance a teacher or online homework system will mark it wrong, so be prepared to explain. (Also in my experience, even this might get you nowhere!)

Answer (score 8):

Who says you went wrong? Subtract the two answers

$$\frac{1}{8}\sec^8x-\frac{1}{8}\tan^8x-\frac{1}{3}\sec^6x-\frac{1}{6}\tan^6x+\frac{1}{4}\sec^4x$$

$$= \frac{(\sec^2x+\tan^2x)(\sec^4x+\tan^4x)}{8} - \frac{\sec^6x}{2} + \frac{(\sec^4x+\sec^2x\tan^2x+\tan^4x)}{6} + \frac{\sec^4x}{4}$$

which is $\frac{1}{24}$, a constant.

Answer (score 3):

You were told the correct answer is
$$ \int \tan^5 x \sec^4 x \,\mathrm dx = 
\frac{\tan^8 x}{8} + \frac{\tan^6 x}{6} + C. $$

You know that $\tan^2 x = \sec^2 x - 1$.
Therefore $\tan^6 x = (\sec^2 x - 1)^3$ and $\tan^8 x = (\sec^2 x - 1)^4$.
Therefore

$$ \frac{\tan^8 x}{8} + \frac{\tan^6 x}{6}
 = \frac{(\sec^2 x - 1)^4}{8} + \frac{(\sec^2 x - 1)^3}{6}. $$

Expand the powers of $\sec^2 x - 1$ and combine like terms. You will find that

$$ \frac{(\sec^2 x - 1)^4}{8} + \frac{(\sec^2 x - 1)^3}{6}
 = \frac{\sec^8 x}{8} - \frac{\sec^6 x}{3} + \frac{\sec^4 x}{4} - \frac{1}{24}, $$

so your answer is correct; all that is different is the constant of integration.

Answer (score -2):

$$\int \tan^5 \theta \cdot \sec^4\theta\, d\theta = 
\int \tan^5\theta(1+\tan^2 \theta)\sec^2\theta \, d\theta$$

Doing the substitution $u=\tan \theta$ ($du=\sec^2\theta\, d\theta$), we get:

$$\int u^5(1+u^2)du=\dfrac{u^6}{6}+\dfrac{u^8}{8}+C=\dfrac{\tan^6\theta}{6}+\dfrac{\tan^8 \theta}{8}+C$$

Comment: Your solution is elegant but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes, this in indeed the correct answer as provided.  I knew that, though.  I'm wondering where I erred in constructing my answer.

Comment: These is equivalent to the OP answer

Comment: I am not sure why this Answer Post is getting downvoted. **It is the Part missing in Question Post itself** , without which the other Answers make no sense. One Answer Post says "Subtract the 2 Answers" ( which 2 Answers ? ). The other Answer Post says "You were told the Correct Answer" ( where was it told ? ). Both make no sense when the Question Post itself has not given the Expected Answer. This Answer Post makes that Part clear & hence this is very useful. +1 from me !

Comment: @nuggethead. I'm not sure your answer is wrong, if not an especially parsimonious approach. Take your answer and subtract mine, but don't assume the C's are the same. Isolate the two (C_1-C_2) to one side and see  if you can simplify the other. I think up to an integration constant hidden by a trig identity, the answers are the same.